# Выведение информации из БД с циклом While и работа с ней через AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, while

Проблема, когда запускаю AJAX заполняя поле onchange="feedback1()", в console дает информацию об id верную, a a1 только первой строки информацию дает в независимости заполнил я поле в первой строке или в любой другой. Что делаю не верно. Спасибо за подсказки.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr><th>№</th><th>Статус</th><th>Имя</th><th>Телефон</th><th>Процедура</th><th>Товар</th><th>Стоимость процедуры</th><th>Стоимость товара</th><th>Время окончания</th><th>7</th></tr>
                        <?
                        while($client = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) //для обработки неск. записей //Уменьшить размер шрифта??
                        {
                            $action_id = $client['id'];
                            $q_items = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM action_items WHERE action_id = '$action_id'");
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input readonly id="id" value="<?=$client['id']?>" size="5"></td> <? //как сделать, чтобы и данные передавались в Ajax и отображалось в браузере не в редактируемом поле, а просто прописывалось???>
                                <td><?=$client['status']?></td>
                                <td><?=$client['name']?></td>
                                <td><?=$client['phone']?></td>
                                <td><?
                                    while ($row_action = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q_items))
                                    {
                                        $checkbox_id = $row_action['checkbox_id'];
                                        $q_act = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM checkbox_action WHERE checkbox_id = '$checkbox_id'");
                                        while ($row_name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q_act))
                                        {
                                            echo "<p>".$row_name['name_action']."</p>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ?></td>
                                <td><?=$client['product']?></td>
                                <td><?=$client['cost']?></td>
                                <td><?=$client['cost_product']?></td>
                                <td><?=$client['date_completion']?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="text" id="a1" name="a1" value=""  onchange="feedback1()">

                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?}
                        ?>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    function feedback1()//При изменении в чекбоксе галочек
    {
    var id = $('#id').val();
    var a1 = $('#a1').val();


    console.log(a1, id);
    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "add_action_ajax.php",
    data: {id:id, a1:a1, feedback1: 1}
    })
    .done(function( msg )
    {
    console.log(msg);
    });
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:
Подставьте $client['id'] и a1

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="text" id="a1" name="a1" value=""  onchange="feedback1(тут $client['id'] и a1)">
```

и отправляйте его в ajax:

```
function feedback1(id, a1)
{
    console.log(id, a1);
    ...
}
```

Что вы делаете не так:
Вы не учли что html элементы имеют уникальный id, поэтому Js отправляет самый первый элемент с id=a1.

Comment: Большое спасибо!